# RTD Sensor Datasheet Details

Tags: sensor, rtd

I need to read one type of rtd sensor using  linked datasheet(page5) but as far as i know there must be a temperature vs resistance table. Am i missing something or given datas are enough to read temperature. I will use 1 ma constant current. Thanks.

http://www.jumo.de/attachments/JUMO/attachmentdownload?id=3404&filename=t90.6121en.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resistance is 1000\$\Omega\$ at 0°C. The sensors follow the DIN IEC-751 (European) RTD curve with \$\alpha\$ = 0.385 so at 100°C the resistance is 1385\$\Omega\$.

You can either look up the table from various [sources](http://www.intech.co.nz/products/temperature/typert/-200to239c.gif)*, use the Callendar VanDusen equation to calculate R(T), or use the polynomial as described in the ITS-90 temperature standard.

*If the table is given for a Pt100 sensor, just multiply the numbers by 10 for Pt1000.

All DIN type platinum RTD sensors should follow the exact same curve, within the specified tolerances- that's a huge advantage of such sensors- they are interchangeable between sensors and between manufacturers of such sensors.

Edit: Here is the Callendar VandDusen equation implementation for a DIN RTD:

> double cvd(double t, double R0)
>     {
>     double A = 3.908E-3;
>     double B = -5.775E-7;
>     double C = -4.183E-12;
>     return R0 * (1 + A *t + B * pow(t,2) + (t - 100)* C* pow(t,3));
>     }

t is the temperature (Kelvin) 
R0 is the resistance at 0°C

That results in the following results from 0..100°C

> For T =  0.00    R = 1000.00
>   For T = 10.00    R = 1039.02
>   For T = 20.00    R = 1077.93
>   For T = 30.00    R = 1116.73
>   For T = 40.00    R = 1155.41
>   For T = 50.00    R = 1193.98
>   For T = 60.00    R = 1232.44
>   For T = 70.00    R = 1270.77
>   For T = 80.00    R = 1308.99
>   For T = 90.00    R = 1347.07
>   For T = 100.00   R = 1385.02

By the way, 1mA is a relatively large current for a Pt1000 RTD. You should check that self heating is not an issue.

Comment: First thanks for response and it is enough. I dont know how to use polynomial you mentioned. Can you give an example for specific temperature upper 100 celcious?

Comment: I suggest you use the Callendar VanDusen equations as the IPS polynomials are designed for 0.392 RTDs. See edit above.

Comment: Datasheet says max current 1mA for pt1000 , if i apply 10ma will i burn sensor or just self heating which i calculate 20C just curios about meanings. Last question is why you dont advice linear interpolation can you guess an error difference between 2 solution.

Comment: Could be a permanent calibration shift. Probably will not fail. Note that the self heating in air spec is with high velocity air (2m/s) blown at it. The self heating in still air will be much worse. Errors depend on temperature range and any numerical errors. Linear interpolation can easily be accurate within the error of sensor and is more numerically stable. You can use a C program to compare the difference between the methods- it won't be bad if you use enough points- RTDs are almost linear to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

PT1000 is a standard curve with the following values:

[image]